# Apache / Wampserver allow https for public web server

Tags: apache, ssl, wamp, public

Good afternoon,

I've setup an apache 2.4.46 web server with all port forwarding rules. It is actually working well and is public (I can access it from internet with my ip address).

Now I want to source a Javascript file for example from another website. Because it is HTTPS, I need to access my server with HTTPS protocol.

So I installed a SSL certificates / key, and I've setup those files :

- httpd.conf (uncommented ssl modules, and included httpd-ssl.conf)
- httpd-ssl.conf (I checked all paths and SSLSession... attributes)

I'm testing with two computers :

The host, and a client.

Test with the host :

- When the host visits http://localhost => working well
- When the host visits https://localhost => working well
- When the host visits http://<local_ip> => working well
- When the host visits https://<local_ip> => working well (with privacy error)
- When the host visits http://<public_ip> => working well
- When the host visits https://<public_ip> => not working

Test with the client :

- When the client visits http://<public_ip> => working well
- When the client visits https://<public_ip> => not working (connection timed out)

My forwarding ports rules :
[Port forwarding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5Ai9.png)

Any idea about what is goind wrong here ?

**EDIT**

The tutorial I used for my set up : [How to enable HTTPS for WAMP Server](http://gist.github.com/danieldogeanu/081dc198a2d727afd6bf01174990ee8d)

Ok, I notice a first thing : I opened the port 80 on my computer but for the 443 I didn't.

My hosting computer inbound rules :
[computer inbound rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7BzAm.png)

I just changed this and tried again : Now I have a different error :
"This website cannot provide a secure connection" => ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

But still cannot connect it with HTTPS...

Comment: What does you ssl conf look like ?

Comment: @PriyankTrivedi I've follow this tutorial https://gist.github.com/danieldogeanu/081dc198a2d727afd6bf01174990ee8d

Comment: Did you port forward port 443 in your router? the ssl port

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes, I made it, same as the one for the HTTP but instead of port 80, I put 443.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who are looking for the answer,

In my httpd-ssl.conf, it was missing this part :

```
<Directory  "c:/wamp64/www/">
    #Options FollowSymLinks
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```